# why is the output of Message and return result different in this Q# example?

Tags: q#

I hope this is not a duplicate question or something I could have answered on my own.  I was not able to find any answer to my question.  I asked Microsoft copilot to explain the difference and it could not provide an answer other than explain what line 35 & 36 (below) do.

Line 35, `Message($"{results}");` output is `[Zero, One, Zero, Zero, One]` but result show on the image below is `10010`.

ChatGPT explained the difference as:

```
So, when you see "10010," it's essentially the binary representation of the results array [Zero, One, Zero, Zero, One]. The leftmost bit corresponds to the first result (Zero), followed by the second result (One), and so on.
```

I am confused :/  It looks like Message() is printing the results in opposite order.  Is that correct?

[image]

```
/// # Sample
/// Quantum Random Number Generator
///
/// # Description
/// This program implements a quantum random number generator by setting qubits
/// in superposition and then using the measurement results as random bits.
namespace Sample {
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Measurement;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;

    @EntryPoint()
    operation Main() : Result[] {
        // Generate 5-bit random number.
        let nBits = 5;
        return GenerateNRandomBits(nBits);
    }

    /// # Summary
    /// Generates N random bits.
    operation GenerateNRandomBits(nBits : Int) : Result[] {
        // Allocate N qubits.
        use register = Qubit[nBits];

        // Set the qubits into superposition of 0 and 1 using the Hadamard
        // operation `H`.
        for qubit in register {
            H(qubit);
        }

        // At this point each has 50% chance of being measured in the |0〉 state
        // and 50% chance of being measured in the |1〉 state.
        // Measure each qubit and reset them all so they can be safely
        // deallocated.
        let results = MResetEachZ(register);
        Message($"{results}");
        return results;
    }
}
```

Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is as the returned result is an array of results, with qubit 0 being in position 0, qubit 1 being in entry 1, etc. which is shown in the usual left to right. Whereas the |ket> representation is written as binary numbers are, with bit 0 to the right, e.g. 0b1100 is decimal 12, not 3.

Comment: Basically one output is left to right and the other is right to left.

Comment: This was confusing, so we've adjusted in the latest release. See release notes at https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp/releases and hopefully this is more intuitive.